# dailymotion api for video comments

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am working with the dailymotion api and wondered if anyone has experience with it to resolve an issue. i am literally collecting thousands of videos based on queries but for some reason, each time I query for comments on each video, the result comes back empty or 0.

Does anyone know whether you require a special token or if comments are not available as I am unable to find one single case of comments appearing for any videos.

```
[{"created_time":1559835628,"id":"x7af84l","comments_total":0},{"created_time":1559835649,"id":"x7af84n","comments_total":0},
```

Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the comments feature is no longer active on Dailymotion.
This explains why you can't get them via our API.

Comment: Do you plan to reactivate it?

Comment: For the moment this feature will remain unavailable